# Do these integrals converge to 0?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume that you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. And you have a positive random variable $Z$, with $E[Z] =1$. You can then define a new probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P')$, where $P'(A)=E[1_AZ]$.

Because of the same $\sigma$-algebra, the R.V. are the same on both space.

I am wondering if r.v. which are convergent in the first space in $L^2(P)$, also are convergent in the second($L^2(P')$) and converge to the same r.v. as in the first space. And I am wondering if a sequence is cauchy in the first space(in $L^2(P))$, they are cauchy in the second$(L^2(P'))$?

I have tried solving this and showing that it is the case. By using examples related to the radon-nikodym-theorem, I think the problem is reduced to this?:

Assume that you have a sequence of positive random variables $\{X_n\}$ for which $\int_\Omega X_n dP \rightarrow 0$. Then we must show that $\int_\Omega X_n ZdP \rightarrow 0$. But is this the case? It seems very likely but I do not quite find the details. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $Z$ to be bounded. Otherwise you can find a r.v $Y$ such that $E Y<\infty$ but $EYZ=\infty$, and then you can take for example $X_n=Y/n$.